# nan appearing in entries of a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, nan

I'm making an 10x10 array with zeros and letting each entry equal a simple enough computation, when I display my matrix a lot of the numbers have a nan in front of them and I'm not sure what it means. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
%pylab inline
x1=[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.5,2.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,8.0,8.9]
y1=[1.0,1.5,1.0,1.2,2.0,9.0,13.0,8.0,8.0,9.0]
Dis1=np.zeros((10,10))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        Dis1[i][j]=sqrt((x1[i]-x1[j])**2-(y1[i]-y1[j])**2)
print(Dis1)
```

Thanks

Comment: square root of a negative number is not a number. You probably meant to write ```((x1[i]-x[j])**2)**(1/2) - ((y1[i]-y[j])**2)**(1/2)``` to calculate the distance?

Comment: I just moved squared difference to inside the parentheses.

Comment: @Kevin: `sqrt(-1)=i `

Comment: Did you mean `sqrt(a + b)` instead of `sqrt(a - b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming, from reading your code, that you're getting the distance between every x1-y1 pair. So you should be using the Pythagorean theorem, which is a^2 + b^2 = c^2, not a^2 - b^2 = c^2.

change your distance calculation to `Dis1[i][j] = sqrt((x1[i] - x1[j]) ** 2 + (y1[i] - y1[j]) ** 2)`

As it is, you're trying to take the square root of potentially negative numbers, which returns NAN.

Answer (score 0):

If you really would want to calculate the matrix `Dis1`, then you have to use [complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number).

```
import numpy as np
x1=[0.0,0.0,1.0,0.5,2.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,8.0,8.9]
x1=np.array(x1, dtype=complex)

y1=[1.0,1.5,1.0,1.2,2.0,9.0,13.0,8.0,8.0,9.0]
y1=np.array(y1, dtype=complex)

Dis1=np.zeros((10,10), dtype=complex)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        Dis1[i][j]=sqrt((x1[i]-x1[j])**2-(y1[i]-y1[j])**2)
```

In your question, each time when you were trying to calculate the `sqrt` of a negative number the output was `nan`. For complex numbers the imaginary part is then non-zero.

```
Dis1.imag

array([[ 0.        ,  0.5       , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  4.79583152,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.        , -0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  3.35410197,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  6.63324958,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.26095202],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  5.38423625,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  6.32455532,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.17898261],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  3.87298335, -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 4.79583152,  3.35410197,  6.63324958,  5.38423625,  6.32455532,
         3.87298335,  0.        , -4.89897949,  4.        ,  3.40440891],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  4.89897949,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  4.        , -0.        ,  0.        ,  0.43588989],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.26095202,  0.        ,  1.17898261,
        -0.        ,  3.40440891, -0.        ,  0.43588989,  0.        ]])
```